# Is table order imporant in mysql when creating relation between them?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, foreign-keys, one-to-many

I have quite simple question. I am creating database administration tool, where user will be able to create relations between tables, but I am not sure if table order is important when creating relations.

For example: I have two tables `'user'(user_id(INT, PRIMARY KEY), name(VARCHAR), email(VARCHAR))` and `'post'(post_id(INT, PRIMARY KEY), content(TEXT), author(INT))`.

When user has selected one column from both tables (`'user'(user_id)` and `'post'(author)`) tool creates a query:

`ALTER TABLE 'user' ADD CONSTRAINT 'user_id_to_author' FOREIGN KEY ('user_id') REFERENCES post('author')`

but if user would select tables in different order (`'post'(author)` and `'user'(user_id)`) then query would look like this:

`ALTER TABLE 'post' ADD CONSTRAINT 'author_to_user_id' FOREIGN KEY ('author') REFERENCES user('user_id')`

Is there any difference between both query's and if so whats is it?

Comment: NOTE: you are using the wrong quotes. Your tool will not work. (except *maybe* for mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining a one-to-many relationship, so the direction of the relationship does matter.

The table that is altered is the child table; many rows may refer to the parent table, through the primary key of the parent table.

For the example given here, a post *belongs to* a user, and many posts may have the same author, so you want:

```
ALTER TABLE post
    ADD CONSTRAINT author_to_user_id
    FOREIGN KEY (author) REFERENCES user(user_id)
```

Note that object names should not be surrounded with single quotes.

Trying to create the relationship the other way around does not make sense. It would imply that a user needs to have a post *before* it can be created.